# Expresión Regular para evitar distinguir entre mayúsculas, minúsculas y acentos

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Busco una expresión regular que no distinga entre mayúsculas, minúsculas y acentos.

Ya que solo me toma las minúsculas, pero las mayúsculas y acentos no.

Lo que busco es simplemente marcar en negritas las palabras que se buscan, aquí este pequeño ejemplo el cual quiero que no distinga entre mayúsculas, minúsculas y acentos:

```
  var palabra = "Mayúscula"
  var busca = "mayu"; 
  var reg = new RegExp(busca, "g");
  
  palabra = palabra.replace(reg, `<b>${busca}</b>`);
```

Si busco con **`Mayú`**, sí las hace negritas correctamente, pero con **`mayu`** no.

¿Cuál expresión regular me podría resolver eso?

y si me pudiesen explicar la sintaxis lo agradecería, ya que no comprendo aún muy bien cómo realizar una `expresión regular` de acuerdo a lo que necesito.

Comment: ¿Y porqué debería ser *mayu* igual a *Mayú*? ¿Es necesario usar expresiones regulares para esto?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Sí, lo necesito, porque quiero que en cualquier de los casos se hagan negritas, independientemente de si escribo **"Mayú"** o **"mayu"**

Comment: @MauricioContreras o simplemente que la parte de la palabra **Mayúsculas**  se haga negrita cuando busque **mayu** sin reemplazar las mayúsculas y letras con acentos.... Podría ser otra solución.

Comment: ¿La comparación de las cadenas es sólo desde el inicio? o si se busca **"ayu"**   no se resalta la "M".

Comment: @Sal , así es, no lo la resalta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/6999690) en el sitio en inglés, debemos de normalizar para volverlo dos caracteres y eliminar los que estén fuera de rango que serán los acentos.

```js
var palabra = "Mayúscula"
var busca = "mayu";

var reg = new RegExp(busca, "gi");

palabra = palabra.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").replace(reg, `<b>${busca}</b>`);
console.log(palabra);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora como para que se parezca un poco a lo que quieres te voy a dar otro ejemplo con campos de texto

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#searchBtn").click(() => {
    var palabra = $("#textContent").text();
    var busca = $("#searchField").val();

    var reg = new RegExp(busca, "gi");

    palabra = palabra.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").replace(reg, `<b>${busca}</b>`);
    $("#results").html(palabra);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchField" type="text" placeholder="texo a buscar" />
<button id="searchBtn">Buscar</button>
<br>
<textarea id="textContent">Este texto contiene una Mayúscula y acentos.</textarea>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: y por ejemplo si busco **mayu** y la palabra original es **Mayúscula**, y quiero que se marque en negrita **Mayú**scula la original en lugar de reemplazarla por **mayu**scula, ¿se podría también?

Comment: @valle50 sí que se puede, basta con no hacer el `replace`, con un simple `match` sabes si la palabra buscada está en el texto. El tema es poner en negrilla la que haga `match`.

Comment: sí, tocaría sacar el índice del match, pero eso va más allá del ámbito de esta pregunta, te recomiendo hacer otra :)